# How to show admin toolbar in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am writing a Drupal theme. And I somehow have hidden my admin bar and forgot about that. But now, my employer tell me to display it again.
So, I want to know, is there any function or variable that can display admin page? As $page or $page_top, for example.

I've overriden almost all files: html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, region.tpl.php, node.tpl.php

Comment: The admin toolbar is not in a region. If anywhere, it would be in `$page_top`. Also, check the HTML to see if it's just hidden through CSS.

Comment: Check if your user have "View Toolbar" rights too ;)

Answer (score 1):

do the following steps:

1. go to module list, in core modules be sure that dashboard is enable.
2. now check your html.tpl.php, you should have the following:

> ```
> <?php print $page_top; ?>
> ```

3. at the end go to the people -> permissions. make sure in Dashboard section, "View the administrative dashboard" is checked for correct roles.